# Disable On Screen Keyboard in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, embedded, touchscreen, on-screen-keyboard

I run Windows Embedded Standard 7 with a multi touch screen (running on the UPDD driver 4.01.10). The system is running an application in kiosk mode with no need for any other input device.

The On Screen Keyboard is disabled in the Ease of Access center (and is not shown initially), but whenever a user touches the screen, a kind of "On Screen Keyboard Quickstart Button" appears at the left side of the screen, looking like this:

[image: Strange button]

The user can use this to slide in the On Screen Keyboard. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: I would look in device manager for a HID keyboard you can disable

Comment: Thanks Moab for the tip. Unfortunately, there is none. Any HID I disable disables the touch interface.

Comment: Did you look under keyboards?, be sure to show hidden devices also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that one can configure this behaviour at "Control Panel" -> "Tablet PC Settings" -> "Other" -> "Input Panel Settings" -> "Opening".

Comment: I will, but it won't let me until the day after tomorrow. =)

Answer (score 3):

- Go to *Options* (click the *Options* button on the keyboard)
- In the window there's the link to enabling/disabling the keyboard at startup.
- Uncheck *Use On-screen Keyboard*
- Reboot computer

Answer (score -5):

I would try deleting (or renaming to be safe) the On Screen Keyboard (osk.exe) file found at `c:\windows\system32\osk.exe`

Comment: While this may actually work, you are renaming a Windows file.  If it comes with Windows, generally you shouldn't be renaming it.  Especially given in situations where the users keyboard may be broken, and they are on the login screen, they can use the OSK to actually log into the machine.  Removing functionality for the sake of solving a simple option issue isn't really a good solution.